# Non-linear ODE $\dot{y}=\frac{a}{y}+be^{ct}$ Behaviour for $t\to \infty$ and $t\to 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If have to assess the behaviour für small and large $t$ of

$$\dot{y}=\frac{a}{y}+be^{-ct}.$$

I know this ODE is a Chini ODE or Abel ODE. I have calculated the implicit solution in Maple (a bit modified).

$$c_1-{\rm erf} \left(1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt {2} \left( cy \left( t
 \right) +b{{\rm e}^{-ct}} \right) }{\sqrt {ac}}}\right)\sqrt {2}
\sqrt {\pi }b-2\,{{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{\frac {(cy(t)+be^{-ct})^2 }{ac}}}}e^{ct}\sqrt {ac}=0$$

I tried to find the behaviour by using taylor approximation and pade approximation, but actually need something like for large $t$ the solution behaves like a exponential function and for small $t$ like a polynomial (or something similar to that).

I would be glad if someone could tell me how one can assess the behaviour step by step.

Comment: For a and b ~1 as a first crude estimate ignore the exponential and find $ y\sim C\sqrt{2at} $ as $t \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Just a rough sketch of how I'd approach this kind of problems (under the assumption that $c \geq 0$):
$$
2y\dot{y} = \frac{dy^2}{dt} = 2a + 2be^{-ct}y \leq K(1+y^2)
$$
for some constant $K > 0$. Put $u = 1+y^2$, we get $\dot{u} \leq Ku$. That is
$$
u(t) \leq e^{Kt}u(0).
$$
Hence $y$ is bounded in any finite time interval, and the solution is global. Asymptotic behaviors can also be analyzed in a similar manner (perhaps with more careful estimates, as I haven't discussed the signs of $a$ and $b$).

Comment: How did you come up with the estimation?

Comment: The first by observing that $y \leq 1+y^2$. The second by $e^{-Kt}\dot{u} -Ke^{-Kt}u = d(e^{-Kt}u)/dt \leq 0$, hence $e^{-Kt}u(t)\leq u(0)$.